# Redux reducer not changing prop

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am making a todo list application with redux. I am able to add todos perfectly fine with redux however my toggle todos and remove todos are having problems.

The toggle todo action gets called by the redux store (I see it happening in the debugger), however, it does not update the prop to be the opposite of completed and I am not sure why.

I have tried playing around with the syntax and modeling other people's redux todo lists for hours but have not been able to solve this issue.

My toggleTodo and removeTodo actions:

```
export const toggleTodo = (item) => {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_TODO,
    id: item.id
  };
};

export const removeTodo = (item) => {
  return {
    type: REMOVE_TODO,
    id: item.id
  };
};
```

My TodoReducer: // this is where I suspect the problem is

```
const initialState = {
  todos: []
};

const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state;
      }
      return {
        ...state, completed: !state.todos.completed
      };
    case REMOVE_TODO: {
      const newState = [...state];
      newState.splice(action.id, 1);
      return { ...newState };
    }
```

My main flatlist where I call the actions:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: HEIGHT }}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.props.todos}
            extraData={this.state}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <TodoItem
                  todoItem={item}
                  pressToToggle={() => this.props.toggleTodo(item)}
                  deleteTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addTodo, toggleTodo, removeTodo })(MainTodo); 
// I call the actions I am using here and don't use mapDispatchToProps
```

And my TodoItem component where I pass in the props:

```
class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const todoItem = this.props.todoItem;
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.todoItem}
          onPress={this.props.pressToToggle}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              color: todoItem.completed ? '#aaaaaa' : '#f5f5f5',
              textDecorationLine: todoItem.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none',
              fontSize: 16 }}
          >
            {todoItem.text}
          </Text>
            <Button
              title='Remove'
              color='#ff5330'
              onPress={this.props.deleteTodo}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I hit toggle todo instead of the prop changing and the line coming through over the text nothing happens.

And when I try to remove a todo I get this error- "invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance."

Comment: Your problem is with your reducer, you are not changing the todos array. You have an array of todos but no-where do you search that array to find the todo that matches the id of the todo that you are trying to update. You also do not update the a todo but add a value to the state `completed` that has no relation to any of the ids of your todos. When you try to remove a todo, you copy the whole state (which is an object) rather than `state.todos` and try to spread it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

when you pass a function to component, try to pass it's reference, instead of

```
<TodoItem
    todoItem={item}
    pressToToggle={() => this.props.toggleTodo(item)}
    deleteTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
/>
```

try

```
<TodoItem
    todoItem={item}
    pressToToggle={this.props.toggleTodo.bind(this)}
    deleteTodo={this.props.removeTodo.bind(this)}
/>
```

and in your **TodoItem** component call the function like

```
class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const todoItem = this.props.todoItem;
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.todoItem}
          onPress={() => this.props.pressToToggle(todoItem)} /* this line */
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              color: todoItem.completed ? '#aaaaaa' : '#f5f5f5',
              textDecorationLine: todoItem.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none',
              fontSize: 16 }}
          >
            {todoItem.text}
          </Text>
            <Button
              title='Remove'
              color='#ff5330'
              onPress={this.props.deleteTodo}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```